# How to Check and Read Number of bytes present in a socket into a byte array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, buffer

I have a C# server that is sending a file (in bytes) to my JAVA client. Currently I am using `DataInputStream` to read data from socket with a buffer size of 1024 bytes and then storing that data in a file.

1. Can anyone tell me how I would know how much data I have received in my socket so that I would adjust my bufferSize accordingly?
2. Is there any other way except `DataInputStream` to read incoming byte data in data from a socket?

Code:

```
DataInputStream In = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(getFilePath(fileName));

int bytesRead = 0;
int bufferSize = 1024;

byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

// fileSize is the int Variable having total Bytes of file that is being sent by server
while (bytesRead < fileSize)
{
    bytesRead += dIn.read(data, 0, bufferSize);
    fos.write(data);
}
```

Hint: I know the size of the incoming file.

Comment: You need to save the return value from `dIn.read()` in a separate variable since that is the number of bytes that have been read in. Then you supply that value as the length to the three-argument form of `fos.write()`.

Comment: You could just replace all of that code with `Files.copy(dIn, Paths.get(getFilePath(fileName)));`.  See [the documentation of Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)).
  I doubt tweaking the buffer size will make a significant difference.

Comment: @VGR It is working well. It is creating the file and copying all bytes in it but the problem is it is blocking the thread even the file has been received and there is no data in the socket.  I have checked the documentation also but I am unable to solve .

Comment: There is no code you can write which will make the socket transfer faster.  If blocking the thread is a problem, move the download to a different thread.  You can use `new Thread`, or an ExecutorService, or CompletableFuture, to name a few options.

Comment: @VGR I am using a new thread, but that new thread is being blocked by read operation if there delay in data, or if the file  has been received. Even after the delay, if data arrives it still blocks the thread. I know it should not happen but it's happening. That's why I said "Is there any other way except DataInputStream to read incoming byte data from a socket?"

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your goal.  It is normal to have some delays on sockets.  That’s why media players buffer their content.  It’s also why InputStream’s documentation address the possibility of blocking during reads.  What effect are you trying to achieve?  Why is the speed of reading the socket a problem?

Answer (score -1):

After a long search, I found one solution. Not perfectly fine, but somehow, it did the job. I used `dataInputStream.available()` to check how many bytes are available and then only read that number of available bytes.

Code:

```
DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(getFilePath(fileName));

int availableBytes = dIn.available();

while (availableBytes> 0) {

Log.d(TAG, "data is available");
size = dIn.read(data, 0, availableBytes);
fos.write(data, 0, size);
availableBytes = dIn.available();

}
```

Comment: **Do not do this.** As [the documentation of available()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) states, the returned value does not determine whether the end of the stream has been reached.  It only indicates how many bytes a caller can try to read without the read method blocking.

Comment: Yes, I knew that's why I have said "Not perfectly fine". If you have any other solution, post it.

Comment: And by the way, I have mentioned in question that "I know the size of file".  So I don't need EOF.